# Get list of installed apps on Android device - C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am using Mono for Android to develop an app in C#.

I need to retrieve a list of installed apps for the device but not sure where to start.

Could anyone point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These could be [this one](http://androidforums.com/application-development/132611-how-can-i-get-list-all-installed-apps.html) or [this](http://androidstream.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/android-how-to-get-installed-applications-list-from-your-application/) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) - these are links for java.

The next thing to look is how to call that java-api from mono - [that for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467469/monodroid-interop-betwen-java-and-c-sharp).

Hope this is good place to start ...